# Create a replica of the list from root site to subsite using JSOM Approach

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, jsom, client-side-rendering

we have requirement to copy the list items from root site list to the subsite list using JSOM/Rest Api

Below are the reasons for which we are going through this option
'

- Our environment does not support powershell scripting (we dont have SCA Access)
- since we dont have SCA Access we cant use tools like sharegate/ metalogix content migration for migrating the tools
- Save List as template does not work as the list has more than 5000 items.

Is this a viable approach to copy list items through JSOM/Rest API,  Source List consists of 13000 Items?

please help us regarding this design